# Return values from an array of method objects

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6

I'm building a date range picker in Vue.js and I have created an array of methods of preset ranges

```
presetRanges:{
  last7Days(){
    return{
      label: 'Last 7 days',
      dateRange:{
        start: this.$moment(today).substract(7, 'd')
      }
    }
  },
  last30Days(){
    return{
      label: 'Last 30 days',
      dateRange:{
        start: this.$moment(today).substract(30, 'd')
      }
    }
  },
  last60Days(){
    return{
      label: 'Last 60 days',
      dateRange:{
        start: this.$moment(today).substract(60, 'd')
      }
    }
  },
}
```

In a for loop, I want to display each method's returned label. The following code is what I used to do, but apparently it doesn't work anymore?

```
<li v-for="(item, idx) in presetRanges" :key="idx">"
  {{ item.label }} 
</li>
```

I have also tried `{{ item().label }}` and it doesn't work either.

Comment: Do you need to create your objects with `()` ? Shouldn't they be looking like `last7Days{` without the brackets ?

Comment: You probably don't want your `last7Days` etc to be the functions, rather you'd probably be better making each `dateRange` a function. As it is, your labels aren't object properties, but instead JavaScript labels. You're missing a pair of curly braces to return an object.

Comment: Sorry, I did have a return in my code, but it's still wouldn't work. I will update the code now for the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably got your structure of your object wrong, the functions should be written as `a: () => ()` in the object, so the solution for your question would be something like this at https://codepen.io/mohithg/pen/VGEjrV?editors=1011

Comment: If it is written using () => in the object, I wouldn't be able to use `this.$moment()`

Comment: You are right. My structure of object was wrong. I have updated it like the example you gave it to me, and now it's working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<li v-for="range in presetRanges">
  {{ range.label }} 
</li>
```

This should work in your case